# atom установить shortcuts

Tags: atom

Добрый день всем! Редактор Atom не могу установить свои сочетания клавиш, в файле keymap.cson пишу:

```
'body':
  'alt-f1': 'core:save-all'
```

Но это сочетание не работает, когда их нажимаешь файлы не сохраняются. Подскажите как быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только посмотрев исходники atom понял где ошибка.
Правильный код :

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-f1': 'window:save-all'
```

Использовать нужно Window!

Answer (score 0):

Вот это должно работать

```
'atom-workspace':
  'alt-f1': 'core:save'
```

Вот это всех вкладок

```
'body':
  'alt-f1': 'window:save-all'
```

P.S. Команда `save-all` работает с `window`

Comment: не-а не работает ))

Comment: @alexandrovdi исправил, должно работать

Comment: P.S. Команду save-all я не нашел, можете сказать откуда она - брал по примеру из атома. А на счет команды так же работает, я все же правильно делаю, пишу команду нажимаю Сохранить и все должно работать? Или что еще нужно сделать?

Comment: в keybindings в настройках сочитание клавиш есть

Comment: @alexandrovdi да, просто сохраняете файл `keymap.cson` и всё должно работать

Comment: @alexandrovdi по поводу `save-all`, я нашел только плагин atom-save-all https://atom.io/packages/atom-save-all, который добавляет свое действие на ctrl+s: `'ctrl-s': 'atom-save-all:saveAll'`

Comment: нет снова не работает)))  загадка века!